# How to get image dimensions in Magnolia CMS

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia, dam

I have an absolute positioned image whose parent container I need to set a height on, but now I can't find a method in magnolia API that allows me to get the width or height of an asset/item.

Is there a way to get Image Dimensions (height, width) of an Asset/Item in Magnolia CMS using only the native API?

If not, how would you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write it somehow like

```
import info.magnolia.dam.api.metadata.MagnoliaAssetMetadata;
// ...
if (asset.supports(MagnoliaAssetMetadata.class)) {
  MagnoliaAssetMetadata metadata = asset.getMetadata(MagnoliaAssetMetadata.class);
  long width = metadata.getWidth();
  long height = metadata.getHeight();
  // do whatever you need with the image dimensions
} else {
  // handle non-image asset
}
```

See [MagnoliaAssetMetadata](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/service/local/repositories/magnolia.public.releases/archive/info/magnolia/dam/magnolia-dam-api/2.1.5/magnolia-dam-api-2.1.5-javadoc.jar/!/info/magnolia/dam/api/metadata/MagnoliaAssetMetadata.html) javadoc and/or sources (and related classes) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I'll mark it as answer, since it answers what I asked for. FYI: In meanwhile I accomplished  to retrieve the metadata using FTL Templating functions that I found on https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Templating+function+arguments+and+return+types#Templatingfunctionargumentsandreturntypes-Mapofanassetanditsmetadata

Answer (score -1):

I have done something like this, base on what you have suggested. I am using **damTemplatingFunctions** to get the asset using the JCR id.

```
Node node = nodes.nextNode();
String imageJcrId = node.getProperty("image").getValue().getString();
Asset asset = damTemplatingFunctions.getAsset(imageJcrId);
MagnoliaAssetMetadata metadata1 = asset.getMetadata(MagnoliaAssetMetadata.class);
System.out.println(metadata1.getHeight());
System.out.println(metadata1.getWidth());
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but the answer is already chosen and verified. your answer is basically exactly the same...